# Send EPOLLIN event to epoll_wait

Tags: c, system-calls, epoll

Is it possible to manually send `EPOLLIN` event to `epoll` for socket file descriptor without writing data to the socket?

Maybe it is possible to use `fcntl` or `ioctl` to stop `epoll_wait` function, isn't it?

*UPDATE*:

I understand that in most cases it does not make sense to do this, but I think it does make sense in my case.

I'm writing a network plugin for a program, which I cannot modify. The plugin API gives me a socket FD and tells me to write a function to read `n` bytes from the socket. I use `ssl_read` function from the `polarssl` library for this, which reads all the data into its own inner buffer, that is more than `n` bytes.

What happens in the program? The program waits (`epoll_wait`) when the socket receives data and then tells the plugin to read about 4kB of data. And then it waits for the next data to be received by the socket. When the socket receives 12kB of data, the program calls the `read` function within the plugin, which reads all the data with `ssl_read` function. As a result, there's no more data available for the socket, but the `polarssl` library has it's own buffer, which has about 8kB of data available.

So now I need to tell the program to call the `read` function of the plugin, which is not going to read data from the socket directly, but is going to read data from inner `polarssl` buffer.

Comment: You want to interrupt `epoll_wait` (remotely?) without sending any data, am I correct?

Comment: @ErkiA, Yes, I want to interrupt epoll_wait without sending any data. But the handler of the epoll_wait result should think that the data is available. (See my update section).

Comment: The `read` function is written by you. Why do you need the program to re-call it to read data from `polarssl` buffer, why can't you do it all in one run?

Comment: @ErkiA, The program has a buffer with the length of 4kB. So when it receives `EPOLLIN` event, it calls my function `read` with 3 parameters: socket FD, pointer to a buffer and its length (<=4096). I search for `ssl_context` assigned to the socket or create new if not found. Then I call `ssl_read` function with 3 parameters: `ssl_context`, pointer to the buffer and its size. But this function reads from the socket more data than the buffer size. Then I have to return the size of data written to the buffer. Then the program handles this data and waits for the next portion of data.

Comment: `EPOLLIN` with no data means "connection closed". So even if you could do what you want (which I think you can't), it is still a very hacky solution and may still not work for you. It seems more logical to fix this from the `polarssl` side, because even if you have to do some "tricks", this end is fully under your control.

Comment: @ErkiA, It's possible to fix from the polarssl side, but I'll have to rewrite many functions like `ssl_read`, `ssl_read_record`, `ssl_handshake`, etc. And this is not good for me.

Answer (score -1):

I pretty sure this link can be helpfull for you https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/

Comment: You should post some content from the provided link, as links can go bad over time.

Comment: Is it possible to manually send EPOLLIN event to epoll for socket file descriptor without writing data to the socket? Yes, but it does not make sense to do this, since the receiving process would not have copies of the file descriptors in the epoll set.

Comment: @user1152213, thanks for the reply, but I don't see the answer for the question from the provided link.

Comment: @user1152213, I've written an update section, where I try to describe why do I need to simulate the `data available` event for the socket.